# Frattini subgroup and generating sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $P$ be a finite $p$-group. It is easy to see that the cardinality of the smallest possible size of a generating set (say, $d(P)$) for $P$ equals the dimension of $P/\Phi(P)$ as vector space.

Now take a subgroup $H$ of $G$. Is it true that $d(H)\leq d(P)$? I know that $\Phi(P)=P^pP'$, therefore $\Phi(H)\leq \Phi(P)$. I think this is an easy thing but I can't figure it out. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in general: $C_{p} \wr C_{p}$ is generated by $2$ elements (where $C_{p}$ is the cyclic group of order $p$ ), but also has an elementary Abelian subgroup of order $p^{p}.$ ( I should have said that $p$ is an odd prime).